# Homebrew pip issue 5599 on Intel macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, python, homebrew, xcode, pip

(I'm new here, so please be gentle)

When using [topgrade](https://github.com/r-darwish/topgrade) in homebrew (I installed topgrade after installing homebrew with `brew install topgrade`) on macOS big sur on a 2020 Intel 13" default upper specs MacBook Pro I ran into the following issue:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Looking for a solution on the web I found [this article](https://andreaolivato.medium.com/how-to-solve-the-invalid-active-developer-path-brew-error-after-updating-to-mac-os-catalina-10-15-e351e743dd23).

Following the advice I ran `xcode-select --install` and restarted afterwards.

After running topgrade again I became a bit suspicious when it said:

```
    ...
Successfully installed pip-21.1.1
    WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.1.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    ...
```

but I though well, seems like it updated itself. So I ran topgrade again and it said

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (21.1.1)
```

Since then I've been getting the same answer. I followed the link but found no solution other than the Python workaround, which seems to be a short term solution.

As far as I know have both pip version 19.2.3 as well as 21.1.1 and need to remove the old one right? But how do I do that? And does `Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (21.1.1)` mean it already fixed itself? And what happens if I ignore the problem?

If anyone could help me out it would really be appreciated. While I love tech I've got no coding experience at all in this is just over my head. That you so much!

**Edit:** I ran the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175827/what-version-of-python-is-on-my-mac) and got the following results:

```
which -a python python2 python2.7 python3 python3.6
```

showed

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3
```

typing `python` and hitting tab (equivalent to `compgen -c python`) gave me

```
python            python2           python2.7-config  pythonw
python-config     python2.7         python3           pythonw2.7
```

and running `locate python` after building the database [like described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175827/what-version-of-python-is-on-my-mac) gave me a super long list, which wouldn't fit here.

**New Question:** I don't really understand the steps I'm supposed to take [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599) before running `python -m pip`, but I don't really see any difference whether or not I do these steps anyway. Can I just run `python -m pip` without really having a clue what happens?

**Second Edit**

`python -m pip --version`
gives `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip`

and
`python3 -m pip --version`
gives
`pip 21.1.1 from /Users/MyName/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Regarding the second comment `python -V` gives
`Python 2.7.16`

and
`python3 -V` gives
`Python 3.8.2`

Also sorry that it's been a while, but we have exams at the moment so I've been kind of busy.

Comment: I have formatted your question lightly for readability and added a relevant link to `topgrade` (I believe). Please look over the question and make any additional changes you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is this:

Figure out what installation of Python you want to be using, make sure that's the one you get when you just type `python` at the prompt, and make sure that the `pip` you get when you just type `pip` points to that same installation.

Apple is moving away from having a default installation of scripting languages including Python, but so far they still come with one - that you don't have permission to upgrade without turning off System Integrity Protection. So the usual advice of "just keep the system install upgraded" is harder to do on Macs.

You get a completely different version when you install Xcode, and it doesn't supply a `python` binary at all, only one called `python3`.

My advice is to install python with Homebrew, so you have full control over it, but it also doesn't provide a `python`, at least not one linked by default. You have to make that link yourself. But I think you should - symlink all the 3-less Homebrew python binaries to /usr/local/bin; and put `/usr/local/bin` in your PATH before any other system-type locations.

So these steps, basically:

```
brew install python
ln -s /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/* /usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin/python -mpip install --upgrade pip
```

Then in your shell startup file (~/.bash_profile or ~/.zprofile or ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc) make sure that /usr/local/bin comes first in your PATH with something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH#/usr/local/bin:}
```

Then quit your shell and start a new one and then you should be good to go.

Comment: typing `pip`results in `zsh: command not found: pip` and typing `python`results in `WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended. 
This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. 
Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7. 
Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

Python 2.7.16 (default, Feb 28 2021, 12:34:25) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.19.59.6) [+internal-os, ptrauth-isa=deploy on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
`and an infinite calculation

Comment: Did you run the three commands and modify your .zprofile and restart your terminal window?

Comment: no, I though I couldn't run them because `pip` and `python` didn't point to the same installation. Also thanks for the quick reply and helping in general!

Comment: also, are these all separate ones?: brew install python
ln -s /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/* /usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin/python -mpip install --upgrade pip

Comment: yes. three separate commands. first install the Homebrew version of Python. Then create links so that you have a 'python' in /usr/local/bin that points to that Homebrew installation. Upgrade pip using that python. Then change your $PATH so you get that python when you type just `python`.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

> As far as I know have both pip version 19.2.3 as well as 21.1.1 and need to remove the old one right?

Regarding removal, not necessarily. While it's certainly more true on Linux, Python is often tightly integrated into *nix-style systems. Messing with a default system installation of Python can (hypothetically) cause failures in key system software (the most visible often being package managers than run Python under the hood).

> How do I do that?

Assuming the older version is part of your system's default Python installation, ideally you shouldn't. In any case, it's often better to use any built-in system tools or take other appropriate steps to upgrade to the most recent versions of the right software (Python/`pip`). The arguable exception to this is any virtual environment or Python application that requires specific versions of Python or any related packages to be installed.

It is probably worth mentioning that while pip 19.2.3 can be used with Python 2 or Python 3, pip 20.3 was the last version to have a `.whl` (Python prebuilt installation file) supporting Python 2. pip 21.0+ is squarely aimed at Python 3. A history of pip releases is available [here](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#history).

> I followed [the link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599) but found no solution other than the Python workaround, which seems to be a short term solution.

The basic advice on that page is solid and will help you avoid problems, assuming you follow it. You should read it carefully.

Note that the reference to using `python -m pip` as a workaround is somewhat misleading. That form is typically the best way to use `pip`, independent of the issue you are encountering. It won't necessarily keep you completely out of trouble but, as a rule, using `pip` by itself often isn't advisable.

> Does `Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (21.1.1)` mean it has already fixed itself?

It likely means that you have a current version of `pip` installed in that installation of Python (`./Library/Python/3.8`) or whatever it refers to. To really find out what's what, you will likely want to check for multiple installations of Python (as a suggestion, see this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175827/what-version-of-python-is-on-my-mac) perhaps for some ideas on how to do that), and then check each installation's version of `pip`.

Note that, as far as I am aware, Xcode installs its own copy of Python 3 (default `python3`, `pip3`)  which is separate from the Python 2 installation MacOS has used in the past by default (often `python`, `pip`).

> What happens if I ignore the problem?

Your computer will crash, turning your screen into the "falling code" from The Matrix and then your system will spontaneously explode. ;)

Seriously, though, I unfortunately don't have an answer for you. You should edit your question with the results of the testing suggested above, which might offer a bit better window into what's happening.

Comment: thanks a million, did so, please check edit

Comment: I checked the edit. Thank you for updating. It doesn't appear you have any extra Python installs in your path. I might suggest running `python -m pip --version` as well as `python3 -m pip --version` to see the exact versions of pip installed with each one and add the full results to your question as well. In short, this should indicate what version of `pip` is in use for each installation (and arguably whether any "problem" is actually with your `pip` installs or potentially something else).

Comment: Regarding new your question, there can be multiple Python instances (interpreters) installed on a system. Each of these are unique. The base installations don't share packages or tools (such as `pip`). So running `python -m pip` "as-is" is really only a solution if you know for certain that (in your case) `python` is referring is not only to Python 3.x but also how that version of Python 3.x relates to whatever `topgrade` is doing. Note that you can check the general version(s) of Python with ex. `python -V` and `python3 -V respectively`. This information could also be helpful if edited in.

Comment: did so, please check